Why is my C# code not finding the dll gstreamer-1.0.dll?
This is my .csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
   <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="gstreamer-sharp-netcore" Version="0.0.8" />
 </ItemGroup>

When I run my C# script:
var rtspsrc = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "source");
var rtph264depay = ElementFactory.Make("rtph264depay", "depay");
var h264parse = ElementFactory.Make("h264parse", "parser");
var mpegtsmux = ElementFactory.Make("mpegtsmux", "muxer");
var hlssink = ElementFactory.Make("hlssink", "sink");

// Elements Config
rtspsrc["location"] = rtspUrl;
rtspsrc["latency"] = 200;
hlssink["location"] = $"{directoryPath}\\%06d.ts";
hlssink["target-duration"] = 5;
hlssink["playlist-location"] = hlsOutputPath;

// Pipeline Creation
var pipeline = new Pipeline("hls-pipeline");

// Linking
rtspsrc.Link(rtph264depay);
rtph264depay.Link(h264parse);
h264parse.Link(mpegtsmux);
mpegtsmux.Link(hlssink);

// Add to pipe
pipeline.Add(rtspsrc, rtph264depay, h264parse, mpegtsmux, hlssink);

// start pipe
var ret = pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);

if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Failure)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.");
    return;
}

// Main Loop
GLib.MainLoop mainLoop = new GLib.MainLoop();
mainLoop.Run();

// dispose...
pipeline.SetState(State.Null);

I get this error on the console:

Error: Unable to load DLL 'gstreamer-1.0-0.dll' or one of its dependencies: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado. (0x8007007E)

I'm using

GSTREAMER SHARP from Visual Studio 2022
GSTREAMER mingw_x86_64 (DEV and MSI)
OS Windows 11

The error occurs when this line is called:
var rtspsrc = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "source");

The first line that uses the Gstreamer sharp library.
The .dll is in a folder that was created when I installed Gstreamer on my machine, I put the paths in the environment variables so that GSTREAMER could use
Screen Capture of Enviroment Variables
What didn't make sense is that when I run something like this:
var pipeline = Parse.Launch("playbin uri=http://download.blender.org/durian/trailer/sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4");"

it works...
I have already configured the GStreamer ENVIRONMENT PATH paths.
I'am a really newbie so could someone explain it to me?
I need GSTREAMER to generate the .ts and .m3u8 files. But it's causing that DLL error.

Which line of code throws that error? Where is the dll file in respect to the script file?

In your .csproj file I'd ensure its being imported properly in there. We can't necessarily identify where the issue is without knowing how you're loading in the file.

@gunr2171 The error occurs when this line is called: "var rtspsrc = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "source");". The first line that uses the Gstreamer sharp library.

@AndrewNarvaez The .dll is in a folder that was created when I installed Gstreamer on my machine, I put the paths in the environment variables so that GSTREAMER could use.

Make sure that also the GStreamer dependencies are properly found: libintl, zlib, libffi, glib. Optional dependencies: ffmpeg, x264, json-glib, graphene, openh264, orc. Also, make sure that all DLLs and the main project share the same CPU-bitness.

@AxelKemper How can I do this?

Use a dependency checker. You could install one of the applications based on GStreamer and try it.

@AxelKemper I tested the application called AmaroK, it worked normally.

Then, the PATH present for calling AmaroK should be configured for your own application. Watch out for space characters within the PATH and quote as necessary.

@AxelKemper In fact, I only installed Amarok, I didn't set up any PATH and it still worked. possibly because I had already set up the paths to Gstreamer previously. Therefore, my C# codes should work... But iam still getting the dll error.

The screen dump of your environment variables shows that your PATH contains other environment variables. These are probably not resolved properly. So, you should use echo %PATH% from a command box and copy the resolved PATH to your configuration.
